# If the cut locus of surface is a segment, the surface is the topologic sphere?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, surfaces, geometric-topology

I drew a few examples and looked at them, seemly, if the cut locus of a surface is a (not closed) segment, then the surface is a topologic sphere.

I google it, but fail to find efficient reference. So, ask here. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to think about this question? What can you say about topology of the complement to the cut locus?

Comment: @MoisheKohan  You really are good teacher. First the complement of the cut locus is the topologic open ball. If the cut locus is a segment, cut  it open. And gluing a disc to the boundary of cuting, then  we have a sphere. Therefore, the origin surface is sphere.

Comment: Right..........